# 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException exception when testing with Selenium WebDriver using C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2015, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm learning Selenium WebDriver with C#.
I'm using Firefox 50.0 and WebDriver 3.0.1 with VS 2015

I have the following code:

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.firefox.marionette", @"pathToDriver");
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.demoqa.com");
```

Exception is thrown on the second line:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException was unhandled   ErrorCode=10022
>   HResult=-2147467259   Message=An invalid argument was supplied
>   NativeErrorCode=10022   Source=System   StackTrace:
>          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType)
>          at OpenQA.Selenium.Internal.PortUtilities.FindFreePort()
>          at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
>          at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor(FirefoxOptions options)
>          at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor()
>          at ToolsQA.FirstTestCase.Main(String[] args) in P:\Eugene's Practice Projects\Selenium\ToolsQA\ToolsQA\FirstTestCase.cs:line 23
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried commenting your first line out? What exception are you receiving?

Comment: The same exception. I even downgraded my Firefox to v 46

Comment: Not sure what your page looks like but you might try going here - http://testerstories.com/2015/10/using-c-with-selenium-webdriver/ and seeing if those examples help.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the exception you are getting into your question?

Comment: I have updated the question with Exception details